# Running Java Program in Eclipse multiple times

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, processing

I wrote a Java program in Eclipse that uses Processing IDE libraries, and it works just fine. This program gets some data from a .csv file and assign those values to the variables inside the program.

I want to make this program run multiple times automatically and sequentially, and before each run I want to modify some of the data from the .csv file so that I can get different outputs at each time.

I've been thinking about this for a long time and couldn't come up with any answer myself. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mert

Comment: You're describing actually writing code.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest way of I can think of is creating infinite for loop, but this is only on the assumption that your question is based on some sort of assignment,

```
     for(;;){

        // read the folder path
        File folder = new File("your folder path");

        if(folder.listFiles().length > 0){

            //read files - your csv file

            //process files - capture any values

            //delete file - delete the file

        }
     }
```

Now you can change the csv file manually, put it in this folder, let the program read it and once it is deleted you will understand it is processed and you can add new file/s.

Also it is not clear that how long due to want the program to run, accordingly you have to take care releasing File resources in your program so they are available for garbage collection.

Hope this helps!!